# How to print out the correct predicted category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tensorflow

Currently able to get the correct prediction, however the printed category string is wrong.

If there is only 2 categories then this code will run perfectly, however now im using 3 categories.

```
CATEGORIES = ["RGB images score 1", "RGB images score 2", "RGB images score 3"]

prediction = model.predict([prepare('score3.png')])

print(prediction[0])  # will be a list in a list.

print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][1])])
```

OUTPUT

```
[0. 0. 1.]

RGB images score 1
```

Actual output should be "RGB images score 3". However I got "RGB images score 1" instead. Only score 3 images have this problem.

Comment: Maybe your model makes some mistakes sometimes. It doesn't know that your image is a `type 3` image. It's its job to know it, but if neural networks were perfect it would be known ;)

Comment: @JosephBudin actually the model predicted it correctly as the first output is [0. 0. 1.] which shows the probability of it belonging to the 3rd category (RGB images score 3) to be 100%

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, I read your outputs too fast, I found the problem, you can find it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at `prediction[0][1]` which is litterally : did the network predict `2`.

It indeed works for 2 categories, but not for more ! You need to find the index for which prediction[0] is equal to 1.

You could use for instance `print(CATEGORIES[int(np.argmax(prediction[0]))])`

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly! Its much better than doing an if else

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, I'd be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it using an if else

```
CATEGORIES = ["RGB images score 1", "RGB images score 2", "RGB images score 3"]

prediction = model.predict([prepare('score3.png')])

if prediction[0][2] == 1.0:
    print("RGB images score 3")

else:
    print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][1])])
```